# Controlar cambios en un imput numérico

Tags: javascript, eventos

Tengo este código de prueba:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fire an input change event</title>
</head>
<body style="padding: 5% 12%">
    <main style="text-align: center">
        <label>
            Input One - use "onchange" event
            <br>
            <input type="number" name="number-one" id="number-one" value="0" step="1">
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>
            Input Two - use "oninput" event
            <br>
            <input type="number" name="number-two" id="number-two" value="0" step="1">
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="button">Añadir 1</button>
    </main>

    <script>
        const inputNodeOne = document.getElementById('number-one');
        inputNodeOne.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            console.log('Input One value: ' + event.target.value);
        });
        const inputNodeTwo = document.getElementById('number-two');
        inputNodeTwo.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
            console.log('Input Two value: ' + event.target.value);
        });

        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            const valueOne = inputNodeOne.value ? parseInt(inputNodeOne.value) : 0;
            const valueTwo = inputNodeTwo.value ? parseInt(inputNodeTwo.value) : 0;

            inputNodeOne.value = valueOne + 1;
            inputNodeTwo.value = valueTwo + 1;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Estoy usando [VainillaJs](http://vanilla-js.com/), la respuesta debería estar en este "lenguaje".

Me planteo **tres formas de cambiar el valor de un *input*** de tipo numérico:

- Introducir el valor con el teclado.
- Usar los controles internos del campo de entrada numérico
- Modificar el valor mediante un script (cambiar por programación), en este caso uso un botón para añadir una unidad.

Necesito ***detectar el cambio en los tres casos*** para recuperar ese valor. Mi problema esta en el tercer caso.

Un evento "onchange" en un *input*, detecta:

- El uso de los controles internos del *input*, en este caso.
- La introducción manual de valores, cuando se pierde el foco. Tanto tecleándolos como pegándolos.

El [evento "oninput"](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp), detecta:

- El uso de los controles internos del *input*, en este caso.
- La introducción manual de valores, automáticamente. Tanto tecleándolos como pegándolos.

> Editado

Entonces queda cubrir el tercer caso, ***detectar que el valor del input ha cambiado si este cambio se hace programáticamente***, en este caso este cambio se hace al pulsar un botón pero podría ocasionarlo cualquier otra acción del usuario o evento del sistema, no quiero detectar estos sino los cambios en el valor del *input*.

Comment: Básicamente, ¿quieres agregarle un +1 a un input númerico desde un botón?

Comment: No logro entender cual es el problema real, no funciona? no se suma? no detecta? En qué estás atorado, modifica tu pregunta.

Comment: @Jorius prueba el código que puse, sumar 1 no es un problema.

Comment: @Alberto_Siurob puse un código de ejemplo funcional, básicamente para ilustrar el problema. De forma resumida **no puedo detectar un cambio realizado programáticamente** en el propio *input*, desde luego puedo "recoger" el cambio en el momento que actualizo el valor del *input*, pero no es esto lo que quiero.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tu pregunta o problema no es clara, al menos me parece que está planteada muy abstractamente y no logro comprender que es lo que quieres realizar

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer referencia al [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target) para saber a cual se esta editando y mandar a llamar una funcion antes de subir para validar cual sea el nuevo valor

ejemplo:

```js
 //seleccionamos todos input de tipo number
    let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
    // funcion up para subi +1 al valor
    function up(nodes){
        // recorre los nodos
        for(let x of nodes){
            // asigna al nodo especifico su valor +1 
            // el + antes x.value es un cast a number
            x.value = +x.value+1;
         }
    }
    //seleccionamos el button y asignamos el evento click
    document.getElementById('button').
      addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        // llamamos a la funcion up y le pasamos como parametro los nodes
        up(nodes);
      });

// detectar cambios en los nodes
for(x of nodes){
// agregamos un evento keyup
 x.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
    // hacemos referencia al node seleccionado
    let self= event.target;
    console.log(`el nodo con id ${self.id} a cambiado su valor a ${self.value}`)
 })
}
```

```html
     <main style="text-align: center">
            <label>
                Input One - use "onchange" event
                <br>
                <input type="number" name="number-one" id="number-one" value="0" step="1">
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>
                Input Two - use "oninput" event
                <br>
                <input type="number" name="number-two" id="number-two" value="0" step="1">
            </label>
            
                    <br>
            <label>
                Input three - use "oninput" event
                <br>
                <input type="number" name="number-three" id="number-three" value="0" step="1">
            </label>
                    <br>
            <label>
                Input four - use "oninput" event
                <br>
                <input type="number" name="number-four" id="number-four" value="0" step="1">
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button id="button">Añadir 1</button>
        </main>
```

Comment: Esto sólo detecta la pulsación del botón y actualiza todos los *inputs*, no es lo que pregunto.

Comment: @orici actulizado para lo que necesitas!

Answer (score 0):

Aporto la solución que he encontrado, usando [Mutation observer](https://es.javascript.info/mutation-observer), *indirectamente* (añadí un atributo al input):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fire an input change event</title>
</head>
<body style="padding: 5% 12%">
    <main style="text-align: center">
        <label>
            Input One - use "MutationObserver" to detect element changes
            <br>
            <input type="number" name="number-one" id="number-one" value="0" step="1" data-number="0">
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button id="button">Añadir 1</button>
    </main>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            const inputNodeOne = document.getElementById('number-one');
            const valueOne = inputNodeOne.value ? parseInt(inputNodeOne.value) : 0;

            inputNodeOne.value          = valueOne + 1;
            inputNodeOne.dataset.number = valueOne + 1;
        });


        // Con MutationObserver puedo detectar los cambios en el valor
        // del input que se hacen al pulsar el botón, añadiendo el nuevo
        // valor en un atributo del input: "data-number"
        const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList) => {
            mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
                console.log('Actual value: ' + mutation.target.dataset.number)
            })
        });

        // Elemento del DOM a observar
        const targetNode = document.getElementById('number-one');
        const observerOptions = {
            attributeFilter: ['data-number']
        };

        observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esta solución no controla los cambios directos sobre el input, introducción de un valor por teclado / pegado o accionando los controles internos del input, para esto hay que añadir un escuchador de evento, como los del código de la pregunta que sí funcionan en estos supuestos.

Answer (score 0):

Una idea que se me ocurre (sencilla, pero me parece que puede solucionar tu problema) sería la de encapsular el valor de tu/s inputs dentro de un objeto, simulando de cierta manera un two data binding.

```js
//Función básica para simular two databindigs
function BingindHelper (element, value) {
    this.value = value;
  this.element = element;
  this.element.value = this.value;
  this.element.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    this.value = this.element.value;
  });
    this.setValue = (value) => {
    this.value = value;
        this.element.value = value;
  }
}

//Defino una constante que tendrá el elemento con su 
const input1 = new BingindHelper(document.getElementById('input'), 15);

//Botón para mostrar que el valor de la variable efectivamente se actualizó.
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(input1.value)
});

//+10 Para mostrar que al modificar la variable (usando el método setValue) actualiza también en la ui.
document.getElementById('plus').addEventListener('click', () => {
    input1.setValue(Number(input1.value)+10);
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number"/>
<button type="button" id="btn">show</button>
<button type="button" id="plus">+10</button>
```

De esta manera, sin mutar la variable, usando un método podrías disparar el mismo evento que en tu UI, sea `onChange` u `onInput`, espero que te pueda servir la idea para avanzarla un poco.

Me basé un poco en la idea que se plantea en [esta pregunta de SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483560/how-to-implement-dom-data-binding-in-javascript), acá quizás podes encontrar un poco más de información si te interesa avanzar esta idea.

Comment: Gracias, lo miro.